# Deciding size of temporary in template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that needs to be able to interpolate between two instances of a type.  So my class calls a user-provided function called `interpolate`, with the following signature:

```
template<typename T>
T interpolate(uint32_t distance, const T& from, const T& to);
```

Here, `distance` runs from `0` to `0xFFFF`.

Now, I would like to provide sane implementations for common types of `T`, such as for `uint32_t`.  So I wrote a sample implementation (ignore that it is only implemented for signed types):

```
template<typename T>
inline auto interpolate(uint32_t distance, const T& from, const T& to)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value, T>
{
    return from + ((distance * (to - from)) / 0xFFFF);
}
```

This works fine for types that are smaller than 32 bits, because distance is never larger than 16 bits' worth, and the result of `distance * (to - from)` is `uint32_t`.  But 32 bits is not enough to contain the result of, say, `0xFFFF * uint32_t` -- in this case the template would need a 64-bit temporary.

Is there a standardized way I can select a type a "size larger" than `T` to hold the temporary result in?  Obviously this only needs to work for intrinsic types; users' types will still need their own `interpolate` implementation.

Comment: Is it a part of the interface that `0xFFFF` is the fixed range for `distance` ?

Comment: You could just use `uintmax_t` for the type (e.g. `(uintmax_t)(to - from) * distance`). Perhaps it'd be good to also include some sort of overflow protection though, e.g. if `to - from` is greater than 2^60 or something, then divide by `0xFFFF` first, or use floating point

Comment: Yes, 0xFFFF is fixed. uintmax_t is a good idea.  Also, I could just constrain the overload to only work with types T such that sizeof(T) < sizeof(uintmax_t).

Comment: if `distance == 0xFFFF`, then wouldn't `((distance * (to - from)) / 0xFFFF)` just be equal to `(to - from)`, and since you do `from + ...`, then wouldn't the return value just be `to` since `from + (to - from) == to`?

Comment: @txtechhelp well, distance runs from `0` to `0xFFFF` (this is an animation framework).  So yes, when the animation is done, we've arrived at `to`.  But in general, it's some value in the range [from, to].  Assuming you don't do something silly like overflow, of course.

Comment: Makes more sense, I was thinking you hard-code `0xFFFF` as a passed value (and thus the compiler might optimize that routine). But you state `in this case the template would need a 64-bit temporary` .. is this a problem that larger types aren't supported? Rather, could you do something to the effect of `auto tmp = (distance * (to - from)) / 0xFFFF; return from + tmp;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you've said, your interpolation factor can only go from 0 to 0xFFFF. You should have a type that reflects that to minimize potential errors - ie don't use `uint32_t` but `uint16_t` instead. As a rule of thumb, you should avoid taking more than you need in parameters. So the general signature is:

```
template<typename T>
T interpolate(uint16_t factor, const T& from, const T& to);
```

Notice that when doing interpolation the result can exceed the range `[from; to]` - as a result, there is no need to have a bigger type in the interface.

Now, you're complexifying your life with integer interpolation. I don't know why on earth you don't want floating point interpolations (especially for an animation framework, we're not in 1995 anymore !).

So, if you really want to do it integer-style, then you'll need a bigger integer to hold it. The simplest you can do:

```
template<typename I> struct bigger_integer;
template<> struct bigger_integer<int8_t>   { typedef int16_t type; };
template<> struct bigger_integer<int16_t>  { typedef int32_t type; };
template<> struct bigger_integer<int32_t>  { typedef int64_t type; };
template<> struct bigger_integer<uint8_t>  { typedef uint16_t type; };
template<> struct bigger_integer<uint16_t> { typedef uint32_t type; };
template<> struct bigger_integer<uint32_t> { typedef uint64_t type; };
```

And, inside your function, use the following bigger type:

```
using I = std::make_signed_t<typename bigger_integer<T>::type>;
```

It should work even for unsigned types with minor modifications.

***My opinion: use doubles***. And if after a profiling session you find that they cause performance problems, then you can try to optimize them. But I honestly doubt it will be the case. Here the code is simpler:

```
template<typename T>
T interpolate(uint16_t factor, const T& from, const T& to)
{
    return T(double(from) + double(factor) * (double(to) - double(from)) / double(0xFFFF));
}
```

[Live example here](https://ideone.com/DDZj5s).

Comment: The reason I can't use floating point is that this is an embedded platform (a Pebble watch) with severe code size limitations and no hardware floating point. The 0 to 0xFFFF is actually the interface that their API provides and that I'm wrapping over. Thanks for the `bigger_integer ` templates; that seems obvious in retrospect...

Comment: Ah I see. I had a working code for integer interpolation, I should post it this evening or tomorrow morning